# Variadic templates and Alexandrescu tuple implementation

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I try to learn a little bit about template metaprogramming and
currently i play around with variadic templates.

In his talk "Variadic Templates are Funadic" Alexandrescu introduces a
small tuple implementation, which i try to build and maybe extend a
little bit. (I know it is a toy example, i just try to learn a little
bit more about c++). However, i have a small problem with his code.

Here it is:

```
template <typename... Ts> 
class tuple
{};

template<size_t, typename> struct tuple_element;

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct tuple_element<0, tuple<T, Ts...>> 
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <size_t k, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct tuple_element<k, tuple<T, Ts...>> 
{
    typedef 
       typename tuple_element<k-1,tuple<Ts...>>::type type;
};

template<size_t k, typename... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<k == 0, 
                        typename tuple_element<0,tuple<Ts...>>::type&>::type
   get(tuple<Ts...>& t)
{return t.head_;}

template<size_t k, typename T, typename... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<k != 0,
                        typename tuple_element<k,tuple<T,Ts...>>::type&>::type
   get(tuple<T,Ts...>& t)
{
    tuple<Ts...> & super = t;
    return get<k-1>(super);
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class tuple<T,Ts...> : private tuple<Ts...> 
{
private:
   T head_;

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
     tuple<int,std::string> t;
     get<0>(t) = 10;
     get<1>(t) = std::string("test");
     std::cout<<get<0>(t)<<std::endl;
}
```

In order to work correctly, the get function must be friend of the
tuple class (It is also mentioned on this slides, see 32). But how
does the friend declaration looks like? I tried different approaches
but could not get it to work. When i change the code from private to public inheritance 
and change the access rules for head_ to public it works.

Thanks for your help

Kevin

Comment: `std::end` on the second to last line should be `std::endl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class tuple<T,Ts...> : private tuple<Ts...> 
{
private:
   T head_;

   template<size_t k, typename T1, typename... T1s>
   friend typename std::enable_if<k != 0,
                        typename tuple_element<k,tuple<T1,T1s...>>::type&>::type
   get(tuple<T1,T1s...>& t);

   template<size_t k, typename... T1s>
   friend typename std::enable_if<k == 0, 
                        typename tuple_element<0,tuple<T1s...>>::type&>::type
   get(tuple<T1s...>& t);

};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/363787fd82327ca0).

Comment: Thank you. I tried this before but forgot to change the template names.

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation from the other point of view:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class... Args>
class Tuple;

template <>
class Tuple<> {};

template <class T, class... Args>
class Tuple<T, Args...>: public Tuple<Args...> {
    using Base = Tuple<Args...>;
    T Value_;

public:
    Tuple(T&& value, Args&&... args)
        : Value_(std::forward<T>(value))
        , Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
    }
    T& Value() {
        return Value_;
    }
};

template <size_t k, class T, class... Args>
struct Select {
    using Type = typename Select<k - 1, Args...>::Type;
};

template <class T, class... Args>
struct Select<0, T, Args...> {
    using Type = T;
};

template <size_t k, class... Args>
using TSelect = typename Select<k, Args...>::Type;

template <bool P, class T>
using TEnableIf = typename std::enable_if<P, T>::type;

template <size_t k, class T, class... Args>
TEnableIf<(k != 0), TSelect<k, T, Args...>&> get(Tuple<T, Args...>& t) {
    return get<k - 1, Args...>(t);
}

template <size_t k, class T, class... Args>
TEnableIf<(k == 0), TSelect<k, T, Args...>&> get(Tuple<T, Args...>& t) {
    return t.Value();
}

int main() {
    Tuple<int, char> t(1, 'a');
    std::cout << get<0>(t) << std::endl;
    std::cout << get<1>(t) << std::endl;
    get<1>(t) = 'b';
    std::cout << get<1>(t) << std::endl;
}
```

Actually, we don't need a Tuple to get a type.